# SpringBoot Error while creating a simple project using spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a SpringBoot application for ecommerce project.
I have two classes one is 'Product' and other is 'product_category'

this is my product class which is mapped to a product table in mysql.

```
   package com.luv2code.ecommerce.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory category;

    @Column(name = "sku")
    private String sku;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "units_in_stock")
    private int unitsInStock;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastUpdated;



}
```

This is my product_category class.

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products;




}
```

I have two repository class for both of them
which are as follow-
for product

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce.dao;


import com.luv2code.ecommerce.entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>{
}
```

for product_category

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce.dao;

import com.luv2code.ecommerce.entity.ProductCategory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "productCategory", path="product-category")
public interface ProductCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductCategory,Long> {
}
```

here is my main application

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootEcommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootEcommerceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I run this app it show lot of error which are as follows

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 2; nested exception is org.tConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal charactorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.sprinorg.story.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.luv2code.ecommerce.SpringBootEcommerceApplication.main(SpringBootEcommerceApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.laorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.addBeans(ApplicationConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addFltSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setBasePath(RepositoryRestConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.to(PropertyMapper.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties.applyTo(RepositoryRestProperties.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.java:61) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:367) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 4: /api  
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2966) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3137) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3219) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904) ~[na:na]
    ... 112 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58325', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using java 16

Comment: anything you specify as /api somewhere?

Comment: no i do not declare anything like that

Comment: how abt in your @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/demo")
public class DemoController {

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying.

Comment: I solved I added two spaces in my application.properties file. Thanks bro

Comment: glad it worked since you are new try to post answers having more context.